# MySQL WHERE 1=2 still showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `view_meeting` WHERE 1=2
```

And it is returning all data, I get the same result using 1=1 also. Why is this?

Does it have something to do with it being a view and not a table?

Comment: I cannot replicate with a view.

Comment: What kind of client are you running this in? Is it possible strings are being cast to integer 0 so 0=0?

Comment: I cannot replicate here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ah yes I have quotes on my numbers in php and am comparing them like '11' < '6' when I did the test above in phpmyadmin with 1=1 it showed all data and then I did 1=2 and the results still showed however I missed the message at the top saying it returned zero results. The previous results just stay on screen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know - the harder I think about it I can't come up with a scenario where numeric string values could actually be mistakenly cast to 0. Could happen with buggy PHP code where variable values aren't as expected, or in a bound parameter expecting an int but getting a non-numeric string.  All a little far-fetched for this scenario.

Comment: @Craig You should post an answer to your own question, since it was just a misreading of phpmyadmin results.

Comment: Voting to close since it was eventually an invalid question.